# Referencing global Ant property after <local> is used

Tags: ant

I can create a [**local** property in Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) within a "block" scope.

But how can I now reference the global property within the same block?

```
<property name="myprop" value="global"/>
...
<sequential>
    <local name="myprop"/>
    <property name="myprop" value="local"/>
    <echo message="my local prop is ${myprop}"/> //<-- this works fine
    <echo message="my global prop is ????"/> //<-- HOW?
</sequential/>
```

No ant-contrib please. 
I'd also like to keep this in Ant, not resorting to JS.

The only thing I could think of was "copying" the global property under a different name to be used in this block

```
    <local name="myglobprop"/>
    <property name"myglobprop" value="${myprop}"/>
    <local name="myprop"/>
    <property name="myprop" value="local"/>
    <echo message="my global prop is ${myglobprop}"/>
```

But that is rather unsightly and seems redundant. I am really just looking for an out-of-scope property reference method.

## ***Edit - use case***

My attempt to coerce Ant to do delayed expansion:

Let's say I have a property whose value is a combination of several other properties.

`<property name="mycmdline" value="${cmd}=${type}"/>`

If `${cmd}` and `${type}` are known before the above property, all is great. However in my case, these values are not defined (no property set). These values only become known at later stage inside a build macrodef.

I have another simple macrodef that will perform delayed expansion:

```
<property name="mycmdline" value="${cmd}=${type}"/>
...
<macrodef name="property-expand">
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="value"/>
    <sequential>
        <fail if="@{name}" message="Property @{name} is already set"/>
        <property name="@{name}" value="@{value}"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Finally my build macrodef would contain the following snippet:

```
<local name="cmd"/>
<local name="type"/>
<local name="mycmdline"/>
<property name="cmd" value="@{cmd}"/>
<property name="type" value="@{type}"/>
<property-expand name="mycmdline" value="${mycmdline}"/>
```

The last line is obviously wrong. I am creating a (now local) property called `mycmdline` with expanded value of global (now out of scope) `${mycmdline}`. The macrodef for delayed expansion works great on it's own, but the problem is that the global `${mycmdline}` is out of scope and cannot be referenced.

What I really wanted is:

```
<property name="mycmdline" value="${cmd}=${type}"/>
...
<!-- In macrodef now -->
<local name="mycmdline"/>
<property-expand name="mycmdline" value="GLOBAL:${mycmdline}"/>
```

Instead, what I have to do is:

```
<property name="unexpanded_mycmdline" value="${cmd}=${type}"/>
...
<!-- In macrodef now -->
<local name="mycmdline"/>
<property-expand name="mycmdline" value="${unexpanded_mycmdline}"/>
```

**Why?**
It may not look like a lot of difference, but it's about readability. `unexpanded_mycmdline` and `mycmdline` are now two different names, when trying to follow the way the value of property gets used through a script, it now makes a disconnected jump from one property name to another (not matter how similar the names may look). The whole `unexpanded_` prefix looks out of place and doesn't fit with the rest of the naming conventions, unless I name all my global variables with some prefix, which doesn't make sense either.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You can't have two properties with the same name, even if they're different types of properties.

Comment: @CAustin, please read about the `<local>` property (link is in the OP). I can assure you that you can definitely have a local property with the same name as a global.

Comment: You can set values to them concurrently, but you cannot reference them individually within the same scope.  If you haven't left the local block, the global value will always be ignored, and if you leave the local block the local value will be forgotten.

Comment: This sounds to be interesting. What's the use case of accessing global-property when you have defined & using it with local-property within your sequential task ??